# Batch file crash when using IF DEFINED

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file to back up my personal files. I made a configuration file which works fine unless I use "IF DEFINED". Then  it crashes. Here is my code for that part:

```
IF DEFINED source_1 (

   IF DEFINED dest_1 (

     IF DEFINED name_1 (

        Other code here

     )
   )
)
```

Even if I take out the code inside that block, it still crashes! Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: There is none. The window just closes.

Comment: Start your batch in an existing command window. Make sure no `echo off` present.

Answer (score 1):

Same code, simpler layout, will not fail.

```
IF DEFINED source_1 IF DEFINED dest_1 IF DEFINED name_1 (

        Other code here

)
```

But your code works fine - test this:

```
@echo off
IF DEFINED source_1 (

   IF DEFINED dest_1 (

     IF DEFINED name_1 (

        echo Other code here

     )
   )
)
pause
```